# Не удается подключиться к расшаренному принтеру 0x00000547

Tags: администрирование, домен, active-directory, принтер

На работе имеет домен, в актив директори, 2 компа. (далее комп 1 с принтером и комп 2 без). Ранее комп 2 под другим пользователем пользовался принтером с компа 2, но сотрудник сменился и с новой учеткой, на комп 2 требуется установить доступ к принтеру компа 1. Но это не удается: в сети комп 2 не может получить к 1 доступ ( 1й светится, если искать со второго), установка принтера не находит его если искать обычным способом, по айпи не удается, а выбрав в актив дирректори вылезает вышеупомянутая ошибка. Если зайти под предыдущим пользователем компа 2, доступ есть, и печатает (принтер установлен). На компе 3 так же ранее получен доступ к принтеру и все ок.

Просьба привести все возможные решения, не ограничиваясь одним и не ожидая моего отклика "помогло ли". Желательно те решения, которые не потребуют переустановки виндовс, прочих радикальных мер, что надолго прервут или сделают невозможной работу на вышеупомянутых железках.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла смена имени машины хоста (комп1). Подскажите в чем была проблема, или  какие нибудь статейки по dns , netbios